Are electrons still present in dead batteries?
After the end of chemical reaction in battery which makes voltage and flow of current, do the electrons existing in copper wire remain there or not?

All those protons in the copper nuclei sure need electrons around.

No offense meant, but you have somehow got a totally wrong understanding so I don't even know how to start an explanation. First thing, there is a difference between the copper wire, which conducts the electrons (taking some up at one end and passing out some at the other end) and the battery, which does not either gain or lose electrons but just pushes some of them to one side. There is a model for a currant that it would be something like a water stream (that will stop if there is no water left to flow) this picture is wrong.

Perhaps a better model would be a hydraulic machine: the water won't run out and the engine is driven by water pressure and not by water as such.

All matter made of atoms contains electrons.

Another picture that might help you is a bicycle chain: if you get too tired to push the pedals, the chain still has all its links.

When a battery goes dead, it has run out of one of its chemical constituents and so the electrochemical reaction that produces a flow of electrons around the circuit to which it is connected is forced to stop. There remain electrons in all the wiring, but there no longer is a voltage difference across the battery terminals which is needed to push those electrons through the circuit.
